# Can I stop excel from formatting my text entirely?

Tags: excel, vba, text, import, ms-word

I'm trying to import text from a Word file into Excel, using VBA and everything is fine and dandy.

However I have not found a way to paste the data as text right away, and some of the values are translated to scientific upon pasting or changing the value (for example 9E17 becomes 9E+1)

Ofc. I could rewrite the code to import all this data line by line and thus set textformat for each cell but i'd rather have Excel not do this at all!

is there a command such as (made-up) application.guessformatofcell = false
wich prevents Excel from changing formatting on its own entirely?

Google and StackExchange searches haven't found me an answer.

Comment: Like @RyanWildry suggested, you haven't provided much in the way of what you have tried so don't know the extent of the text you are copying over but if you add `'` infront of your text before you assign it to the cell, it should keep your format

Comment: What commands are you using to do this **import** form **Word**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Text"
```

Comment: though this does not seem to answer the question per se, I have, up to this date no reason reason to assume there is a function such as the above mentioned/asked. This is therefore the simplest work-around